# How to Convert Pdf file into bitmap image

Tags: android

i am unable to find correct source code for this.while i am  downloading and adding the source code  I am getting errors like class cannot find create class.of course i added some of the jars are in library also.please provide some proper and useful code for that.

Answer (score 1):

To convert pdf to images use [android-pdfview](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview) and following code

```
DecodeServiceBase decodeService = new DecodeServiceBase(new PdfContext());
decodeService.setContentResolver(mContext.getContentResolver());

// a bit long running
decodeService.open(Uri.fromFile(pdf));

int pageCount = decodeService.getPageCount();
for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
PdfPage page = decodeService.getPage(i);
RectF rectF = new RectF(0, 0, 1, 1);

// do a fit center to 1920x1080
double scaleBy = Math.min(AndroidUtils.PHOTO_WIDTH_PIXELS / (double)     page.getWidth(), //
        AndroidUtils.PHOTO_HEIGHT_PIXELS / (double) page.getHeight());
int with = (int) (page.getWidth() * scaleBy);
int height = (int) (page.getHeight() * scaleBy);

// you can change these values as you to zoom in/out
// and even distort (scale without maintaining the aspect ratio)
// the resulting images

// Long running
Bitmap bitmap = page.renderBitmap(with, height, rectF);

try {
    File outputFile = new File(mOutputDir, System.currentTimeMillis() + FileUtils.DOT_JPEG);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

    // a bit long running
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);

    outputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    LogWrapper.fatalError(e);
}
}
```

You should perform this task in background e.g. AsyncTask

Comment: we have to add any library along with this code

Comment: You have to use the library at https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview

Comment: after writing code what u send we have to add only this jar graddle-wrapper.jar or anything else

Comment: also make sure you are writing this code in a background task e.g. AsyncTask

Comment: sorry I am new to android and I didn't understand background means

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9671602/1798737 for Asynstask example and write this code in doInBackground() function.

Comment: thanq so much Muhammad Hamza Shahid

Comment: i added library still i'm facing errors in the code

Comment: What's the error? its better to post a new question for that with complete log and code.

Comment: if iam trying to keep a question it is showing like use grammer even iam using right english.

Comment: Can you tell the error and in which its occuring?

Comment: at DeviceServiceBase class create the class

Comment: sorry at DecodeServiceBase class

Comment: and also variable mOutputDir in try block where it is created

Comment: mOutputDir is the path to directory where the newly created image will be stored you can initialize it like String mOutputDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString()

Comment: what is mContext in doInBackGround method

Comment: Replace mContext with ActivityName.this

Comment: u please tell how to add library

Comment: also variable pdf not created

Comment: To add library check Gthub intructions are there and pdf is the is the File variable of pdf file that you need to process

Comment: bro iam getting so many errors after adding library into work space hava a look on  this screen shot

Comment: how to keep images pls suggest

Comment: u given source code but u r not responding for the errors it is giving.